How do I find the date before a value changes in T-SQL?
So I have a following table:
CreatedAt                    ID    NewStatus    OldStatus
2023-03-08 13:34:57.0000000 1645    Draft        NULL
2023-03-22 19:58:51.0000000 1645    Active       Draft
2023-04-29 05:59:02.0000000 1645    Closed      Active
2023-05-08 14:50:29.0000000 1645    Awarded     Closed
2023-05-08 14:53:34.0000000 1645    ConfirmationStarted Awarded
2023-05-08 17:53:55.0000000 1645    ConfirmationDone    ConfirmationStarted

I want to fetch the date where this ID got "Closed" before "ConfirmationStarted" so in this case i would get the following result
ID    xdate
1645  2023-04-29 05:59:02.0000000

I wrote a T-SQL query:
WITH StatusChanges AS (
    SELECT 
        ID,
        newstatus,
        oldstatus,
        CreatedAt,
        LEAD(newstatus) OVER (PARTITION BY IDORDER BY CreatedAt) AS next_status

    FROM 
        tableA 
        
)
SELECT 
    ID,
   MAX(CreatedAt) AS xdate
FROM 
    StatusChanges
WHERE 
    next_status = 'Confirmation Started' and OldStatus = 'Closed'
GROUP BY 
    ID;

this query works well for most cases such as this ID
CreatedAt                      ID     NewStatus     OldStatus
2022-05-25 23:17:44.0000000 147 Active  Closed
2022-05-28 05:59:02.0000000 147 Closed  Active
2022-05-30 20:48:53.0000000 147 Active  Closed
2022-06-18 05:59:01.0000000 147 Closed  Active
2022-06-21 20:09:48.0000000 147 Active  Closed
2022-06-25 05:59:01.0000000 147 Closed  Active
2022-07-13 00:02:47.0000000 147 ConfirmationStarted Closed
2022-07-15 15:33:30.0000000 147 ConfirmationDone    ConfirmationStarted

and I get my desired date: 2022-06-25 05:59:01.0000000
how do I handle the case with 1645 ID?

This can be done using GROUP BY and HAVING clauses, the condition is that that the row indicating Closed status must precede the row indicating ConfirmationStarted status :
SELECT ID, MAX(CASE WHEN NewStatus = 'Closed' THEN CreatedAt END) AS xdate
FROM mytable
WHERE NewStatus in ('Closed','ConfirmationStarted')
GROUP BY ID
HAVING MAX(CASE WHEN NewStatus = 'Closed' THEN CreatedAt END)
       < MAX(CASE WHEN NewStatus = 'ConfirmationStarted' THEN CreatedAt END)

For this dataset :
CREATE TABLE mytable (
  CreatedAt    datetime,                
  ID           int,
  NewStatus    varchar(30),
  OldStatus    varchar(30)
);

INSERT INTO mytable VALUES
('2023-03-08 13:34:57', 1645,    'Draft',        NULL),
('2023-03-22 19:58:51', 1645,    'Active',      'Draft'),
('2023-04-29 05:59:02', 1645,    'Closed' ,     'Active'),
('2023-05-08 14:50:29', 1645,    'Awarded',     'Closed'),
('2023-05-08 14:53:34', 1645,    'ConfirmationStarted', 'Awarded'),
('2023-05-08 17:53:55', 1645,    'ConfirmationDone',    'ConfirmationStarted'),
('2022-05-25 23:17:44', 147, 'Active',  'Closed'),
('2022-05-28 05:59:02', 147, 'Closed',  'Active'),
('2022-05-30 20:48:53', 147, 'Active',  'Closed'),
('2022-06-18 05:59:01', 147, 'Closed',  'Active'),
('2022-06-21 20:09:48', 147, 'Active',  'Closed'),
('2022-06-25 05:59:01', 147, 'Closed',  'Active'),
('2022-07-13 00:02:47', 147, 'ConfirmationStarted', 'Closed'),
('2022-07-15 15:33:30', 147, 'ConfirmationDone',    'ConfirmationStarted');

Results :
ID      xdate
147     2022-06-25 05:59:01.000
1645    2023-04-29 05:59:02.000

Demo here

cannot thank you enough! i was struggling the entire 5 hours today. I have accepted your answer. Thank you once again!

Glad to hear I could help :) enjoy SQLying
